# What time does cron.monthly jobs run in SLES?

Tags: linux, cron

doc says cron.monthly  will be scheduled according to the first run time and it compares /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly with current time to run. Question is will it run according to the DAILY_TIME directive in /etc/sysconfig/cron file or the /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly time. If it follows /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly should I have to touch the file when I want the job to be scheuled???

Answer (score 0):

### When does cron run monthly cronjobs?

`cron` starts monthly cronjobs once a month at `/var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly`'s modification time (or more exactly, sometime within a 15-minute range after that time).

You can see that in `/usr/lib/cron/run-crons`, which is started **every 15 minutes** in `/etc/crontab`:

```
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons >/dev/null 2>&1
```

When dealing with monthly cronjobs `/usr/lib/cron/run-crons`:

1. Checks whether `cron.monthly` in `/var/spool/cron/lastrun/` is older than one month.
2. Skips monthly cronjobs if it's not.
3. Otherwise, deletes the lock file:

   ```
   eval find $SPOOL/$BASE $TIME | \
             xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
   ```

   adds the monthly cronjob to the run list:

   ```
   if test ! -e $SPOOL/$BASE ; then
       # accept this dir, if it isn't empty 
       LIST=`find $CRONDIR ! -type d`
       if [ ! -z "$LIST" ] ; then
           RUN="${RUN} ${TIME_EXT}"
       fi
   fi
   ```

   and runs the jobs.

### How can I schedule monthly cronjobs?

- If you want the monthly cronjobs to run now (that is, in the next 15 minutes), delete `/var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly`.
- If you want the monthly cronjobs to run at say, 3am starting today, do:

  ```
  $ touch -d "$(date -d "3am last month")" /var/spool/cron/lastrun/cron.monthly
  ```

  Modify the command above to your needs.

### The `DAILY_TIME` variable

The `DAILY_TIME` variable only applies to daily cron jobs, as can be seen in `/usr/lib/cron/run-crons` and documented in `/etc/sysconfig/cron`:

```
# At which time cron.daily should start. (...)
DAILY_TIME=""
```